# How to assert all variables equal in z3py?

Tags: z3py

To assert all elements of a list equal, is there no "Equal()" in z3py? There is for example `Distinct()`.
Using numpy works:

```py
from z3 import *
import numpy as np

s = Solver()

B = [BitVec(f"b{j}", 7) for j in range(11)]

C_eq = [B[i] == B[j] for i in range(3) for j in range(3) if i != j]

s.add(C_eq)

print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed z3py supports `Distinct`, but not `Equals`. The reason is that a straightforward encoding of `Distinct` requires quadratic number of constraints, and it can bog the solver down. Having a `Distinct` primitive allows the solver to avoid this bottleneck. `Equals`, however, only requires a linear number of constraints in the number of variables and typically doesn't need any special help to be efficient.

To simplify your programming, you can define it yourself, however. Something like this:

```py
from z3 import *

def Equals(*xs):
    constr = True
    if xs:
        base = xs[0]
        for x in xs[1:]:
            constr = And(constr, base == x)
    return constr
```

And then use it like this:

```
x, y, z = Ints('x y z')
print(Equals())
print(Equals(x))
print(Equals(x, y))
print(Equals(x, y, z))
```

which prints:

```
True
True
And(True, x == y)
And(And(True, x == y), x == z)
```